# Mongodb $elemMatch query inside map

Tags: mongodb, dictionary

I need to search inside a map element with a certain value in mongodb.

I have this element in data base:

```
{
  "_id": ObjectId("52950e93c4aad399cff0d9f9"),
  "_class": "com.company.model.customer.DbCustomer",
  "version": NumberLong(0),
  "channels": {
    "adea3d4e-2a73-4f3e-8a89-a336d6132909": {
      "value": "dominik.czech.aal@gmail.com",
      "alias": "email1",
      "deliveryChannel": "EMAIL",
      "status": "GOOD",
      "_class": "com.company.model.customer.CustomerEmail"
    }
  }
}
```

Where "adea3d4e-2a73-4f3e-8a89-a336d6132909" is a key of a map of channels.

What I want to search is a channel with certain value.

If "channels" were an array the query would be this way:

```
{ "channels" : 
  { "$elemMatch" : { "value" : "dominik.czech.aal@gmail.com" } }
}
```

But, as channels is a map, I can't use this approach.

Is it possible to search inside a map the same way you search inside an array?

Notice that I want to use a single query, for security reasons I cannot use the map reduce functionality in my database.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is frequently asked. You can't query by the key.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAIK it's not possible with the current MongoDB operators anyway, without scripting or map/reduce or knowing the keys you want to query in advance.

As a side note, you should think your data structure against how you want to query it - i.e. you should probably consider transform the channels document into an array.

Comment: Yes I am late...I totally agree with your side note but it is not as the answer from @nish71 shows, it is however possible to do the query the OP ask for. That is why this should not be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 1):

Your sample code does not contain an array which have to look like `[1, 2, 3]`.

Therefore you have to search in a sub-field like the following example:

```
db.Collection.find({"channels.value" : "dominik.czech.aal@gmail.com"})
```

Hope this will help.....

Comment: I tried your proposed solution, but it didn't work. Yes, there is no array in the sample code, that's why I'm trying to find another solution; if there were an array, the $elemMath solution would solve my problem. Thanks anyway.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. Works perfectly fine and is even scriptable e.g. in pymongo with something like `db.collection.find({f"{key}.{subkey}": {value}}) `.